# Первый снег выпал в октябре. Первый - числит. или прил.?

Tags: числительные

Вопрос возник оттого, что **первый** здесь имеет значение "ранний", а у числительных такого значения нет. Или это всё равно числительное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос можно найти в толковом словаре, в современном языке слово является **числительным или прилагательным (две разные функции).**

**ПЕРВЫЙ,  I. числ. порядк.** к Один (1 зн.). **II. прил. 1. Первоначальный, самый ранний; происходящий, действующий раньше других.** П-ое впечатление. **2. Лучший из всех в каком-л. отношении; отличный.** П. ученик в классе. П-ое лицо (руководитель какого-л. предприятия, учреждения).

Answer (score 2):

Оно здесь не имеет значения "ранний". Но в сочетаниях типа первый снег, первый учитель, первый бал и т.п. ("вторых" и "третьих" не бывает) – это прилагательное.

Answer (score 1):

*Первый учитель и первый урок,

Первый учебник и первый листок.

Первые буквы большого труда,

Хочется, хочется снова туда...*

Грамматические, словоизменительные и синтаксические особенности порядковых числительных совпадают с грамматическими свойствами имен прилагательных. Некоторые грамматисты утверждают, что "правильнее, в соответствии с их свойствами, называть эти слова порядковыми прилагательными"...

Интересно, что уже в глубокой древности счетно-порядковые слова занимали промежуточное положение между именами числительными и именами прилагательными. Наряду с основным значением...им было свойственно приобретать новую семантику, связанную с называнием *качества, свойства* предметов. Например, первый - не только "первый по счету", ***но и "лучший", "главный", "начальный", "старший".***

Так, например, в словосочетаниях *в первую минуту, с первого слова, в первое время,* *первая молодость, с первого взгляда* лексема первый синонимична *прилагательным **"начальный", "ранний"*** :
*Я, можете себе представить, в первую минуту не узнал вас* (то есть сначала).
*Как это бывает в первой молодости и особенно в одиноком положении, он почувствовал беспричинную нежность к этому молодому человеку* (то есть в ранней молодости).

Слово первый может употребляться как прилагательное со значением ***"главный", "единственный" :***
*Она - первый человек в этом доме* - то есть самый главный.
*Это я тебе одному и первому говорю, потому что люблю тебя* - то есть единственному.
http://old.kpfu.ru/fil/kn2/index.php?sod=13

*Первый луч, первый дождь,

По весеннему Арбату ты идешь,

Первый звук, первый снег -

Эта песня о тебе и обо мне...*

Так что **первый** в Вашем примере - **прилагательное**.

Answer (score 1):

Принадлежность слова к числительным устанавливается по тому, возможно или нет его включение в счётную последовательность. В счётный ряд не допускается введение слов других классов. Также, и определение числительного как числительного в отдельной фразе устанавливается по цифровой записи (первый снег — *1-й снег*?), т. е. её правомерности.

*Первый* восходит к корню со значением «передний» и в подобных фразеологизмах несёт лишь эту смысловую нагрузку; в таком сочетании это порядковое числительное выступает прилагательным.

Answer (score 0):

"Первый" - порядковое числительное, отвечающее на вопрос: который? 
Однако если оно имеет значение "ранний" - как вы нам уже сказали, - то это прилагательное.

Answer (score 0):

Имя числительное может быть любым членом предложения:

подлежащим, сказуемым,  дополнением,    определением,   обстоятельством.

«Три толстяка» - замечательная книга.
Семью шесть – сорок два.    Мальчик купил пять тетрадей.
Первое испытание прошло успешно.
В 2014 году в Сочи пройдут зимние Олимпийские игры.

Comment: Не о членстве в предложении речь.